# Razor at-sign variables usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, at-command

How to use at-signed (@) variables at razor templates.
Example:

Updated:

```
@ {
var rng = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);
var @string = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
}

<ul>
@foreach(var i in rng) {
  <li>
    @(@string[i])
  </li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you surround the variable name with parentheses. So:

```
@(@string)
```

Comment: @MystereMan Sorry, have less tahn 15 reputation, so can't vote yet.

Comment: You can still click the little, green checkmark under the downvote button though. This not only ensures I get proper credit, but that the correct answer appears at the top.